# How to allow dll files uploads in wamp server

Tags: dll, upload, wamp, wampserver

I'm using WampServer64 and I'm trying to upload some dll files to
my website without. However I'm not having any luck, they are getting blocked for some reason. Does anyone know why and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you checking the `$_FILES['?????']['error']` array to see if you are getting an error that explains the problem? [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change the settings in php.ini located in 
apache folder and not in the one located in the php folder 
to check if the changes have been made run phpinfo();